# Is it possible to implement Proximity not by using NFC but using any other functionality that can transfer messages

Tags: windows-phone, nfc, proximity, peer

I am reading articles about Proximity on Windows Phone. I have the following ideea. I have an app that can exchange small messages between two phones through encoded audio. Can I use proximity and replace NFC support with my app that transfer messages using sound. I need only an advice if the NFC usage in proximity can be replaced with any other functionality that can intentionally send certain messages. I want to know if it;s a good ideea to pursue my concept.

Thanks

Comment: You rather use sound than Bluetooth and WiFi direct?

Comment: I would want to use sound for pairing, that's why I was refering to the NFC. What I was understanding is that proximity uses wifi for transferring data but the pairing could be done by NFC. If my understanding are wrong, my bad. I am not really a programer but I have a mandatory project to deliver :(

Comment: You can pair using NFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, Windows Phone OS is not a LEGO constructor where you can replace core system services with your own implementation.
At least not with any documented API.
And if you'll use some undocumented APIs, forget about the windows store.

You can probably do that if you're representing an OEM company that builds windows phone devices.

If you're an individual, what you're trying to do might be possible with Android OS. Search for something like "android building custom ROM".

P.S. I think it's a great idea to pursue your concept.
I really miss the simplicity of IR ports in devices.
Very likely, your acoustic pairing could do the job just as good, while requiring no extra hardware.

Comment: Thank you for you time and encouragement, I m thinking for another use case for my message sending app through sound:)